# Is a supported version of avast for 64 bit laptops?

Tags: antivirus

I have been trying to install avast for a while on a 64 bit system...but it only seems to support 32 bit systems. Is there any way to make it work though?

Thanks.

Comment: yes and no - it depends on your ubuntu version whether you can force the installation - but unlikely to be "supported": http://forum.avast.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=aeqn1ho6q81o3tvh674i197a66&topic=79220.msg653529#msg653529

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.04 introduced the support of [Multiarch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec) which means that you can install i386 (32 bit) packages on an installation of a 64 bit system.
So if you have Ubuntu 11.04 and up you will be able to install the 32bit package of Avast.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an extract from this [how to](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-a-32bit-programme-in-64bit-ubuntu/). It shows the terminal commands for installing a 32bit package on a 64bit ubuntu system.

> First, check to see if the package you want is available in 64bit. Try
>   googling around, 32bit will have i386 or i586 in the name, whereas
>   amd64 indicated 64bit. You might want to incluse amd64 in your search
>   terms.
>
> If not, then you’ll have to pretend you’re on 32bit.
>
> Start by running the following in the terminal, providing your
>   password when prompted.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
> ```
>
> If you prefer the Software Center, then search for ia32-libs. Yomight
>   have to click “Show # Technical Items” (bottom left).
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i Downloads/your-package.deb
> ```

Replace your-package.deb with avast-6.0.something.deb and you're all set.